# How to create MD5 checksum for tar files in maven

Tags: maven, tar, checksum

I have a set of tar files. I wanted to create MD5 checksum for those files using Maven. How to do it?

i created this tar files using maven-assembly-plugin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Creating artifact checksums](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/examples/installing-checksums.html) told us as

The Install Plugin can create integrity checksums (MD5, SHA-1) for the artifacts during installation.

```bsh
mvn install -DcreateChecksum=true
```

#### Updated

To generate the checksum for other file the [checksum-maven-plugin](http://nicoulaj.github.io/checksum-maven-plugin/index.html) may help. It provides the [checksum:file](http://nicoulaj.github.io/checksum-maven-plugin/file-mojo.html) as the following usage: -

```bsh
mvn checksum:file -Dfile=some-file.zip
```

It also provides [the custom checksum algorithms](http://nicoulaj.github.io/checksum-maven-plugin/examples/using-custom-checksum-algorithms.html) , e.g. MD5, SHA-1, SHA-256 and so on.

Comment: i don't want to create checksum for the artifacts. i have to create checksums for some random tar files.

Comment: Just an update that `-DcreateChecksum=true` does not work since maven-install-plugin v 3.0.0: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/   https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MINSTALL-143

Answer (score 1):

The capability of creating checksums has been removed from the `maven-install-plugin` version 3.0. The last version where it was available was 2.5.2:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install-file \
  -DcreateChecksum=true
```